# Worldclim and Interpolation

Tags: climate

I am interested in work with climate data since 2012, I found it in http://www.worldclim.org/version1, but there is something draws my attention:

There it says: "Current conditions (interpolations of observed data, representative of 1960-1990)"

Does it mean the current data is something like a "temporal projection" based in data of 1960-1990?
or

Should I understand it like an interpolation of weather stations existing since 1960 with not including stations existing since 1990?

Comment: This has been answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219244/worldclim-current-conditions-interpolations-of-observed-data-representative

Comment: Answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/219250